# Find camera coordinate of vanishing point

Tags: opengl, c++, vector

Given a vector and a camera (position, angle, up vector, field of view, etc), how would I find the vanishing point of the vector in camera space?

Comment: I think you just need to find an intersection point of zfar plane and a line of your vector. And then you can transform this point to any space you want.